# cannot render any of my code to my react-appliaction

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am making a Typescript and React app. I am using 4 main files, App.tsx, Header.tsx, Ap.css. I think the real problem is the way I am trying to use the add the Header.tsx file to App.tsx.

Please help

App.tsx:

```tsx
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.tsx:

```tsx
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";

function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="nav-container">
      <nav>
        <a href="#!">Home</a>
        <a href="#!">About</a>
        <a href="#!">Projects</a>
        <a href="#!">Resume</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Header;
```

App.css:

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: #171A25;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Header.css:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #121625;
}
.nav-container {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect to see vs what do you actually see? Are there any errors reported in your terminal or the browser dev-tools console?

Comment: No repro ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-meadow-9m6yp1?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I am expecting to see a header that is described by the Header.tsx file. What I see now is just a blue background. And no there are no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is nothing wrong with your import method. I think you should check your webpack.config.js file. In resolve part should contain ts and tsx types.

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
```

and also you have to add tsconfig.json file to your project.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/